# How long would the consumer group alive after the consumers dead?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say, I've a topic with two partitions P1, P2 and I've two consumers C1, C2 in a consumer group CG1. Now each consumer is consuming messages from one partition. Now both the consumer are dead because of some reason. In this situation,

1. what happens to the consumer group? Would it be still alive? If yes, how long would it be alive without any consumers joining the consumer group?
2. How can i see the offset details of each partition for this consumer group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[3.1 Broker Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) Default retention period is 7 days which is `10080` minutes, if the consumer is inactive for 7 days then offset of that consumer group will be removed

**offsets.retention.minutes:** After a consumer group loses all its consumers (i.e. becomes empty) its offsets will be kept for this retention period before getting discarded. For standalone consumers (using manual assignment), offsets will be expired after the time of last commit plus this retention period.

```
Type: intDefault: 10080 Valid Values: [1,...] Importance: highUpdate Mode: read-only
```

[Checking consumer position](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag) you can view the consumer's offset for each partition by using following commands

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

Comment: Thanks for the details.